# Good base converter or using gbase?

Tags: linux, utilities

Could you suggest a good base converter that also does "signed" conversions? Either `gbase` does not do it, or I can't see how it's done. What I want to do is give the program an integer, say, -100, and I need to know the binary byte representation of it (in the example, 1 byte, first bit set to 1). I could possibly calculate this number by hand, but I got to do 1000s of them, and bigger than a single byte.

Comment: There's probably something missing in your question: the binary representation of a negative number is just the binary representation of its opposite with a `-` tacked on at the beginning. Do you mean you want the *unsigned* representation modulo N? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/gbase.1.html), gbase has a parameter `-s` to enter signed numbers.